# Shifting hierarchyid set

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchyid

I have a table that contains a set of values and a hierarchyid column. Looks something like this:

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|  ID | HierarchyID |  Name     | HierarchyID.ToString() for clarity
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|   1 |        0x58 | Testing   | /1/
|   2 |      0x5AC0 | TChild1   | /1/1
|   3 |      0x5AD6 | TChild1.1 | /1/1/1
|   4 |      0x5ADA | TChild1.2 | /1/1/2/
|   5 |        0x68 | Example   | /2/
|   6 |      0x6AC0 | EChild1   | /2/1
| ... |         ... |       ... | 
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

However, we are introducing a new data set of that aligns side by side with the current tree and I'll need to shift all the values in my current tree down a level so it should look something like this now.

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|  ID | HierarchyID |  Name     | HierarchyID.ToString() for clarity
+-----+-------------+-----------+
|     |        0x58 | OldData   | /1/
|   1 |      0x5AC0 | Testing   | /1/1/
|   2 |      0x5AC6 | TChild1   | /1/1/1
|   3 |    0x5AD6B0 | TChild1.1 | /1/1/1/1
|   4 |    0x5AD6D0 | TChild1.2 | /1/1/1/2/
|   5 |      0x5B40 | Example   | /1/2/
|   6 |      0x5B56 | EChild1   | /1/2/1
|   6 |        0x68 | NewData   | /2
|   6 |      0x6AC0 | NChild1   | /2/1
| ... |         ... |       ... | 
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

Is there an easy way to update all of my hierarchyid values to shift them down a level or do I have to update each row one by one without overlapping values on updates?

Comment: Show table structure, sample data, and desired results.  I have no idea what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking up the documentation. 
There is an easy way to move a subtree.

[Working with hierarchyid Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677212(v=sql.105).aspx)

Under Moving Subtree there is an example for an Employee hierarchy.
You will have to adjust to your table structure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MoveOrg(@oldMgr nvarchar(256), @newMgr nvarchar(256) )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @nold hierarchyid, @nnew hierarchyid
SELECT @nold = OrgNode FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo WHERE LoginID = @oldMgr ;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT @nnew = OrgNode FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo WHERE LoginID = @newMgr ;

SELECT @nnew = @nnew.GetDescendant(max(OrgNode), NULL) 
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo WHERE OrgNode.GetAncestor(1)=@nnew ;

UPDATE HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
SET OrgNode = OrgNode.GetReparentedValue(@nold, @nnew)
WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@nold) = 1 ; 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END ;
GO
```