# How to move hierarchyid subtree if the new parent has already got children?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, hierarchyid

I guess the problem is described in the title pretty well. I've got a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employees] (
[Id] INT identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
,[Hid] HIERARCHYID NOT NULL
,[Name] VARCHAR(50) NULL
,[Secondname] VARCHAR(50)
,[Surname] VARCHAR(50)
,[BossId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Employees]([Id])
,[PositionId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Positions]([Id])
,[DepartmentId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Departments]([Id])
,[RecruitDate] DATE NOT NULL
);
```

And I need to change employee's boss from one to another. Obviously, there is a nice solution -  **GetReparentedValue()**, and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051975/shifting-hierarchyid-set) example that seemed to be exactly what I needed.
But this solution happens to be not working. **Hid.GetAncestor(1)** is equal to previous BossHid. Probably, the problem is that it can't work well if new parent already got children. That really upsets me. Does it mean I need to write recursive CTE on my own?
Here is the code that was supposed to be working but it didn't:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployee @Id INT
    ,@Name VARCHAR(50)
    ,@Secondname VARCHAR(50)
    ,@Surname VARCHAR(50)
    ,@BossId INT
    ,@PosId INT
    ,@DepId INT
    ,@Rdate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @BossExist INT
        ,@OldBossHid HIERARCHYID
        ,@NewBossHid HIERARCHYID
        ,@LastHid HIERARCHYID;

    SELECT @BossExist = count(*)
    FROM dbo.Employees
    WHERE [Hid] = HIERARCHYID::GetRoot();

    IF @BossExist != 0
        AND @BossId IS NULL
        RETURN;

    SELECT @OldBossHid = (
            SELECT [Hid].GetAncestor(1)
            FROM dbo.Employees
            WHERE @Id = [Id]
            );

    SELECT @NewBossHid = (
            SELECT [Hid].GetAncestor(1)
            FROM dbo.Employees
            WHERE @BossId = BossId
            );

    SELECT @LastHid = @NewBossHid.GetDescendant(MAX([Hid]), NULL)
    FROM dbo.Employees
    WHERE [Hid].GetAncestor(1) = @NewBossHid;

    UPDATE dbo.Employees
    SET [Hid] = [Hid].GetReparentedValue(@OldBossHid, @NewBossHid)
    WHERE [Hid].IsDescendantOf(@OldBossHid) = 1;

    UPDATE dbo.Employees
    SET [Name] = @Name
        ,[Secondname] = @Secondname
        ,[Surname] = @Surname
        ,[BossId] = @BossId
        ,[PositionId] = @PosId
        ,[DepartmentId] = @DepId
        ,[RecruitDate] = @Rdate
    WHERE @Id = Id;
END
GO
```

Thank you.

Comment: I find the way that MS describes using hierarchyid to be difficult to understand and implement in practice. What I've found works works well is rather than let SQL Server assign the constituent values in the path I use the ID of the entity. So, `/1/15/36` means that EmployeeID 36 has Employee 15 as a parent and that one has Employee 1 as their parent. All that said, can you provide a minimal reproducible example? That is, a table with sample data so we can work on it. I have an idea of what you're running in to but the example would help.

Comment: One thing that stands out to me though is the calculation of `@NewBossHid`. Why are you calling `GetAncestor` there? Shouldn't it just be the HID of the passed in Boss?

Comment: Consider combination of Id-ParentId and HierarchyId approaches: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1192607/Combination-of-Id-ParentId-and-HierarchyId